# Where will Web API resides in Blazor full stack project?

Tags: blazor

Before Blazor, we create web api in web application web api project template project. But now, we have Blazor Web Assembly which has "ASP.NET Core Hosted" option which can have web api as well. I am a little confused between these 2 options.

Comment: "Blazor Hosted" is a combination of 2 projects: An API server and a Wasm client. You could make a separate (traditional) API server, then just don't check the Hosted chkbox for Blazor.

Answer (score 1):

It is same as having Angular/React as frontend with AspNetCore project as backend for Web API?

1. BlazorApp.Client -> FrontEnd part - Place any front end code here.
2. BlazorApp.Server -> BackEnd part - For Web API, Authentication and can act as data layer.
3. BlazorApp.Shared -> Mostly for holding shared classes between client and server part.

Comment: But last time if using Angular/React, web api is still in Web Application Web Api project template. But with Blazor with Client/Server/Share template, this Web Application Web Api project template is no longer in used?